# TamperMonkey stimulate press enter does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 16; // # Some key code value
$("textarea.my_input").trigger(e);
```

However, this does not work.(Selector is correct since if i do focus(), it works). I'm wondering that did I do something wrong with it? It seems very straightforward but I can't get it to work. Or is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: You can't _really_ stimulate a keypress other than on code you register since it won't be a trusted event.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So it's not possible in this case?

Comment: It seems you're trying to add a line feed to a textarea. The easiest would be to use `.each()` to iterate through all elements and manually append the LFCR using `.val()`.

Comment: @Derija93 Hi I'm actually trying to develop a plugin so it can automatically submit the form for users. That textarea got submitted once you press enter.

Comment: Then try submitting the corresponding form directly using `$('#form-selector').submit()`, though you may face the same issue of a non-trusted event. I usually try to intercept form submissions, so I never tried it this way...

Comment: @Derija93 well it's not technically a form so I can't submit it. It's more a like a text field so once you press enter, the server calls an ajax call or something to send this value. There is no <form> tags around.

Comment: In that case a simple keydown (or maybe keypress?) event should satisfy since there probably is another handler bound to those events to handle the request... which makes it weird.

Comment: @Derija93 Right.since the focus works so I know the selector must be correct, but the keypress/keydown are both not working.

Comment: Your best bet would be to reverse engineer the website's JavaScript to find out which event particularly is used. If it's minified, try [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {        
        $("textarea.my_input").focus();        
        $("textarea.my_input").append(String.fromCharCode(e.which));        
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JcdxC/2/)

Comment: Hi, I don't thin it's working since my_input got submitted once the enter is pressed. I;m not simply appending \n in the textarea. :-)

Comment: see my edit. You looked on my previous code. and you can block the enter key from outside. but this is the main idea.

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your help but it does not press enter :( the focus works fine tho so at least i know my selector is correct.